# Allowing Apache and SFTP to have write permission

Tags: centos, sftp, apache2, upload

How can I give write permission to Apache as-well as SFTP without having to chown the /var/www directory to apache when it needs to write something and having to chown sftp when I need to upload something?

I'm new to Centos - so please excuse the question, I haven't found a good solution to this question hence why I am asking it again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setfacl](https://www.tecmint.com/secure-files-using-acls-in-linux/) command to set permission on particular files and folders without doing chown